# How do I get the Wings of Valor Pre-order bonus?

Tags: diablo-iii

I pre-ordered the physical game but it won't arrive until April 1, 2014...

The CSR said a code is bundled with the game.  I don't know if this is true or they're just misinformed.

Elsewhere I read that any copy of Reaper of Souls activated before March 31, 2014 will receive the wings.

So if I go to the store and buy it, activate it, is it all just the same?

Comment: totally offtopic, but read this: http://www.cad-comic.com/cad/20140324

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I think in your case you won't receive the wings. Currently I can only find information that says that March 31st is the last possible date for entering your game code to receive the wings ([Diablo Wiki](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Wings_of_Valor) for example).

Since you already ordered it, I think the best thing you can do now is entering the game-key ASAP and hope for the wings to show up.

If you receive them, there will be a message Icon on the bottom left of your screen while in-game (in an act not a menu). But as it seems there has also been [a bug with this which should be fixed by now](http://www.vg247.com/2014/03/21/diablo-3-players-to-receive-missing-items-this-weekend-wings-of-valor-delivery-delayed-for-some/).

Edit: You can get the Pre-Order bonus after April 1. 2014 by contacting support.
      [Source](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-iii-reaper-of-souls-loot)